# Annoying popup in Windows 11. How do I get rid of it?

Tags: windows, popups

My desktop PC is using Windows 11.

Starting a few days back, every 15 minutes or so I get the following annoying popup:

[image]

Which fades away after a few seconds. I cannot click or right-click on it.

I tried to stop a few services but had no luck.

Any ideas what is this and how to stop it? at this time I do not believe this is a side effect of a virus/malware,

Comment: Look in Task Manager, Details, for any process that might be connected with that spam.

Comment: Not malware nor spam. It seems to be something the new Gaming mode does.

Comment: Try [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and drag the bullseye over this window. This will find the process that's issuing it.

Comment: What is your computer brand and model? Is this part of an audio driver utility feature perhaps?

Comment: This is sometimes seen on MSI devices with gaming mode. You should be able to look at the MSI graphics settings and disable it, or turn it off for whatever apps you're using.

Comment: @harrymc  could you please elaborate, Are you saying drag and drop the screenshot somewhere in process explorer?

Comment: @Music2myear My mistake, this is a cyborg MSIA12Vlaptop. And you are likely to be correct.

Comment: @ Adam Thompson, Yes I'm also suspicious this can be a setting under MSI Center. but I cannot find it.

Comment: @SNash ProcExp has a "target" tool that allows you to identify the process associated with the application visible on your screen. When you see the thing you took a screenshot of you drag this target over that thing, not the screenshot, and ProcExp will tell you which process has generated it.

Comment: @SNash: Start ProcExp and have it ready. When the appears click on the bullseye icon, keep pressing and drag it over the dialog, then release it. ProcExp should have selected the originating process. Double click it for details.

Comment: Thank you both I will give it a try.

Comment: Thanks a LOT!   Detected MSIAPService.exe.

Comment: What a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Process Explorer]

Drag that icon (SONAR scope? Bull's eye?) onto a window to have Sysinternals' [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) identify the process and its handles.

**N.B.** This is just a visual clarification of HarryMC comment -- I did not even know of that ID button until he mentioned it. He should rewrite this answer and get credit.